# Is it always appropriate to omit the verb to be from a passive voice sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

I can replace

> A solution is needed urgently.
>   Newer version has already been installed.

with

> A solution needed urgently.
>   Newer version already installed.

Is this kind of omission always correct?

Comment: It's spelled "uRgently" and I think you meant to say "INappropriate" in the title but as I'm not 100% sure, I cannot edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

Not in normal English, whether spoken or written.

The shorter sentences are examples of "[Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)", used in newspaper headlines, captions of pictures, notices, forms etc.

Answer (score -2):

No. It is usually always wrong. You are confusing abbreviated sentences with correct English.